# State not being retrieved in Material UI/Enzyme Test?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, enzyme

I'm mounting my component, and I set the state in the constructor like so.

It's a bit unclear on why this is not working. From the documents that I have read, it is saying that mount will fully render the component and subcomponents and it should call render, constructor, and a few other lifecycle functions. Is there something that I am missing that is causing the state to not be on the ReactWrapper?

```
class UserBox extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      logOutMenuOpen: false,
      anchorElement: null,
    };
  }

  render() {...}
}

//TESTS BELOW

import React from 'react';
import { createMount } from '@material-ui/core/test-utils';
import UserBox from './UserBox';

describe('User Box', () => {
  let closedUserBox;
  let openedUserBox;
  const mount = createMount();
  beforeEach(() => {
    closedUserBox = mount(<UserBox />);
    openedUserBox = mount(<UserBox open />);
  });
  afterEach(() => {
    closedUserBox.unmount();
    openedUserBox.unmount();
  });
  describe('Opened User Box', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
      openedUserBox = mount(<UserBox open />);
    });
    afterEach(() => {
      openedUserBox.unmount();
    });

    it('should have expandedAvatar class', () => {
      const avatar = openedUserBox.find('#userAvatar').first();
      expect(avatar).not.toBeUndefined();
      expect(avatar.prop('className')).toContain('expandedAvatar');
    });

    it('Should open logout menu on menu clicked', () => {
      const state = openedUserBox.state(); //returns null
      const anotherState = openedUserBox.instance().state(); //returns null    });
  });
```

Comment: What do you export from `Userbox.js`?

Comment: @epsilon `export default withStyles(styles, { withTheme: true })(UserBox);`

for clarity, I am importing  `import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';` at the top of the file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`withStyles` is a HOC which means it wraps another component around yours.

So `mount(withStyles(UserBox)).state()` will be the state of the HOC not the actual component. You would need to extract the original component.

You should not test your components like this but if you really think you should test implementation details then you could do something like `wrapper.find('UserBox').state()`. Enzyme will look for a component with the display name `UserBox` which should be your original component with the state.

Comment: +1 Thank you! What would be the recommended way to test this sort of thing then? I'm not very familiar with React yet, so any resources would be appreciated.